# Google form still need to sign-in

Tags: google-forms, anonymous

I have a google form that I unticked "Collect emails", and unticked "Limit to 1 response", and still the form required sign-in to be filled. Any other ideas to allow anyone to fill it without a google account?

[image: form current setting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form includes file upload, then files will get uploaded to their own Drive first, that's probably why an email is still required.